# Unable to get the xml attributes as column names with the XSLT

Tags: java, xslt

This is my sample xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<FIXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2 fixml-main-5-0-SP2_.xsd" s="2012-04-23" v="FIX.5.0SP2">
  <Batch ID="RPTTA111PUBLI20170518">
<MktDef MktID="XEEE" MktSegID="19478" EfctvBizDt="2017-05-22" NxtEfctvBizDt="2017-05-23" MktSeg="C1B1" MarketSegmentDesc="GERMAN INTRADAY CAP FUTURE" Sym="DE000A160PX2" ParentMktSegmID="FENE" Ccy="EUR" MktSegStat="1" USFirmFlag="Y" PartID="10">
  <MtchRules MtchRuleProdCmplx="1" MtchAlgo="PT"/>
  <BaseTrdgRules QtSideInd="1" FastMktPctg="0">
    <TickRules TickRuleProdCmplx="1" StartTickPxRng="0" EndTickPxRng="99999.9999" TickIncr="0.001"/>
    <QuotSizeRules MinBidSz="1" MinOfrSz="1" FastMktInd="0"/>
    <QuotSizeRules MinBidSz="1" MinOfrSz="1" FastMktInd="1"/>
    <PxRngRules PxRngRuleID="178" PxRngProdCmplx="1" StartPxRng="0" EndPxRng="99999.9999" PxRngValu="0.5"/>
  </BaseTrdgRules>
  <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="L" MDBkTyp="2" MktDepth="5" MktDepthTmIntvl="3500" MDRcvryTmIntvl="30000" SvcLctnID1="224.0.50.82" SvcLctnSubID1="59500" SvcLctnID2="224.0.50.210" SvcLctnSubID2="59500"/>
  <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="HS" MDBkTyp="2" MktDepth="10" MDRcvryTmIntvl="120000" SvcLctnID1="224.0.50.106" SvcLctnSubID1="59500" SvcLctnID2="224.0.50.234" SvcLctnSubID2="59500"/>
  <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="HI" MDBkTyp="2" MktDepth="10" MktDepthTmIntvl="0" SvcLctnID1="224.0.50.107" SvcLctnSubID1="59501" SvcLctnID2="224.0.50.235" SvcLctnSubID2="59501"/>
</MktDef>
<SecDef PriSetPx="1.195">
  <Instrmt ID="483878" Src="M" SecTyp="FUT" Status="1" ProdCmplx="1" CFI="FFMCSX" MatDt="2017-06-06" MMY="201706" Mult="168" ValMeth="FUT" SettlMeth="C" PxPrcsn="3" MinPxIncr="0.001" MinPxIncrAmt="0.001">
    <AID AltID="41222169" AltIDSrc="M"/>
    <AID AltID="XF00000407B3" AltIDSrc="4"/>
    <Evnt EventTyp="7" Dt="2017-06-06"/>
  </Instrmt>
  <MktSegGrp MktSegID="19478">
    <SecTrdgRules>
      <BaseTrdgRules>
        <PxRngRules PxRngRuleID="178"/>
      </BaseTrdgRules>
    </SecTrdgRules>
  </MktSegGrp>
</SecDef>
<SecDef PriSetPx="0.001">
  <Instrmt ID="491139" Src="M" SecTyp="FUT" Status="1" ProdCmplx="1" CFI="FFMCSX" MatDt="2017-07-05" MMY="201707" Mult="168" ValMeth="FUT" SettlMeth="C" PxPrcsn="3" MinPxIncr="0.001" MinPxIncrAmt="0.001">
    <AID AltID="41222170" AltIDSrc="M"/>
    <AID AltID="XF0000046RY9" AltIDSrc="4"/>
    <Evnt EventTyp="7" Dt="2017-07-05"/>
  </Instrmt>
  <MktSegGrp MktSegID="19478">
    <SecTrdgRules>
      <BaseTrdgRules>
        <PxRngRules PxRngRuleID="178"/>
      </BaseTrdgRules>
    </SecTrdgRules>
  </MktSegGrp>
</SecDef>
<MktDef MktID="XEEE" MktSegID="19479" EfctvBizDt="2017-05-22" NxtEfctvBizDt="2017-05-23" MktSeg="C1B2" MarketSegmentDesc="GERMAN INTRADAY CAP FUTURE" Sym="DE000A160PY0" ParentMktSegmID="FENE" Ccy="EUR" MktSegStat="1" USFirmFlag="Y" PartID="10">
  <MtchRules MtchRuleProdCmplx="1" MtchAlgo="PT"/>
  <BaseTrdgRules QtSideInd="1" FastMktPctg="0">
    <TickRules TickRuleProdCmplx="1" StartTickPxRng="0" EndTickPxRng="99999.9999" TickIncr="0.001"/>
    <QuotSizeRules MinBidSz="1" MinOfrSz="1" FastMktInd="0"/>
    <QuotSizeRules MinBidSz="1" MinOfrSz="1" FastMktInd="1"/>
    <PxRngRules PxRngRuleID="178" PxRngProdCmplx="1" StartPxRng="0" EndPxRng="99999.9999" PxRngValu="0.5"/>
  </BaseTrdgRules>
  <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="L" MDBkTyp="2" MktDepth="5" MktDepthTmIntvl="3500" MDRcvryTmIntvl="30000" SvcLctnID1="224.0.50.82" SvcLctnSubID1="59500" SvcLctnID2="224.0.50.210" SvcLctnSubID2="59500"/>
  <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="HS" MDBkTyp="2" MktDepth="10" MDRcvryTmIntvl="120000" SvcLctnID1="224.0.50.106" SvcLctnSubID1="59500" SvcLctnID2="224.0.50.234" SvcLctnSubID2="59500"/>
  <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="HI" MDBkTyp="2" MktDepth="10" MktDepthTmIntvl="0" SvcLctnID1="224.0.50.107" SvcLctnSubID1="59501" SvcLctnID2="224.0.50.235" SvcLctnSubID2="59501"/>
</MktDef>
<SecDef PriSetPx="0.587">
  <Instrmt ID="483879" Src="M" SecTyp="FUT" Status="1" ProdCmplx="1" CFI="FFMCSX" MatDt="2017-06-13" MMY="201706" Mult="168" ValMeth="FUT" SettlMeth="C" PxPrcsn="3" MinPxIncr="0.001" MinPxIncrAmt="0.001">
    <AID AltID="41287705" AltIDSrc="M"/>
    <AID AltID="XF00000407C1" AltIDSrc="4"/>
    <Evnt EventTyp="7" Dt="2017-06-13"/>
  </Instrmt>
  <MktSegGrp MktSegID="19479">
    <SecTrdgRules>
      <BaseTrdgRules>
        <PxRngRules PxRngRuleID="178"/>
      </BaseTrdgRules>
    </SecTrdgRules>
  </MktSegGrp>
</SecDef>
<SecDef PriSetPx="0.001">
  <Instrmt ID="493745" Src="M" SecTyp="FUT" Status="1" ProdCmplx="1" CFI="FFMCSX" MatDt="2017-07-12" MMY="201707" Mult="168" ValMeth="FUT" SettlMeth="C" PxPrcsn="3" MinPxIncr="0.001" MinPxIncrAmt="0.001">
    <AID AltID="41287706" AltIDSrc="M"/>
    <AID AltID="XF0000049F05" AltIDSrc="4"/>
    <Evnt EventTyp="7" Dt="2017-07-12"/>
  </Instrmt>
  <MktSegGrp MktSegID="19479">
    <SecTrdgRules>
      <BaseTrdgRules>
        <PxRngRules PxRngRuleID="178"/>
      </BaseTrdgRules>
    </SecTrdgRules>
  </MktSegGrp>
</SecDef>
<MktDef MktID="XEEE" MktSegID="19480" EfctvBizDt="2017-05-22" NxtEfctvBizDt="2017-05-23" MktSeg="C1B3" MarketSegmentDesc="GERMAN INTRADAY CAP FUTURE" Sym="DE000A160PZ7" ParentMktSegmID="FENE" Ccy="EUR" MktSegStat="1" USFirmFlag="Y" PartID="10">
  <MtchRules MtchRuleProdCmplx="1" MtchAlgo="PT"/>
  <BaseTrdgRules QtSideInd="1" FastMktPctg="0">
    <TickRules TickRuleProdCmplx="1" StartTickPxRng="0" EndTickPxRng="99999.9999" TickIncr="0.001"/>
    <QuotSizeRules MinBidSz="1" MinOfrSz="1" FastMktInd="0"/>
    <QuotSizeRules MinBidSz="1" MinOfrSz="1" FastMktInd="1"/>
    <PxRngRules PxRngRuleID="178" PxRngProdCmplx="1" StartPxRng="0" EndPxRng="99999.9999" PxRngValu="0.5"/>
  </BaseTrdgRules>
  <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="L" MDBkTyp="2" MktDepth="5" MktDepthTmIntvl="3500" MDRcvryTmIntvl="30000" SvcLctnID1="224.0.50.82" SvcLctnSubID1="59500" SvcLctnID2="224.0.50.210" SvcLctnSubID2="59500"/>
  <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="HS" MDBkTyp="2" MktDepth="10" MDRcvryTmIntvl="120000" SvcLctnID1="224.0.50.106" SvcLctnSubID1="59500" SvcLctnID2="224.0.50.234" SvcLctnSubID2="59500"/>
  <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="HI" MDBkTyp="2" MktDepth="10" MktDepthTmIntvl="0" SvcLctnID1="224.0.50.107" SvcLctnSubID1="59501" SvcLctnID2="224.0.50.235" SvcLctnSubID2="59501"/>
</MktDef>
<SecDef PriSetPx="0.777">
  <Instrmt ID="483880" Src="M" SecTyp="FUT" Status="1" ProdCmplx="1" CFI="FFMCSX" MatDt="2017-06-21" MMY="201706" Mult="168" ValMeth="FUT" SettlMeth="C" PxPrcsn="3" MinPxIncr="0.001" MinPxIncrAmt="0.001">
    <AID AltID="41353241" AltIDSrc="M"/>
    <AID AltID="XF00000407D9" AltIDSrc="4"/>
    <Evnt EventTyp="7" Dt="2017-06-21"/>
  </Instrmt>
  <MktSegGrp MktSegID="19480">
    <SecTrdgRules>
      <BaseTrdgRules>
        <PxRngRules PxRngRuleID="178"/>
      </BaseTrdgRules>
    </SecTrdgRules>
  </MktSegGrp>
</SecDef>
<SecDef PriSetPx="0.001">
  <Instrmt ID="495690" Src="M" SecTyp="FUT" Status="1" ProdCmplx="1" CFI="FFMCSX" MatDt="2017-07-19" MMY="201707" Mult="168" ValMeth="FUT" SettlMeth="C" PxPrcsn="3" MinPxIncr="0.001" MinPxIncrAmt="0.001">
    <AID AltID="41353242" AltIDSrc="M"/>
    <AID AltID="XF000004B602" AltIDSrc="4"/>
    <Evnt EventTyp="7" Dt="2017-07-19"/>
  </Instrmt>
  <MktSegGrp MktSegID="19480">
    <SecTrdgRules>
      <BaseTrdgRules>
        <PxRngRules PxRngRuleID="178"/>
      </BaseTrdgRules>
    </SecTrdgRules>
  </MktSegGrp>
</SecDef>
<MktDef MktID="XEEE" MktSegID="19481" EfctvBizDt="2017-05-22" NxtEfctvBizDt="2017-05-23" MktSeg="C1B4" MarketSegmentDesc="GERMAN INTRADAY CAP FUTURE" Sym="DE000A160P05" ParentMktSegmID="FENE" Ccy="EUR" MktSegStat="1" USFirmFlag="Y" PartID="10">
  <MtchRules MtchRuleProdCmplx="1" MtchAlgo="PT"/>
  <BaseTrdgRules QtSideInd="1" FastMktPctg="0">
    <TickRules TickRuleProdCmplx="1" StartTickPxRng="0" EndTickPxRng="99999.9999" TickIncr="0.001"/>
    <QuotSizeRules MinBidSz="1" MinOfrSz="1" FastMktInd="0"/>
    <QuotSizeRules MinBidSz="1" MinOfrSz="1" FastMktInd="1"/>
    <PxRngRules PxRngRuleID="178" PxRngProdCmplx="1" StartPxRng="0" EndPxRng="99999.9999" PxRngValu="0.5"/>
  </BaseTrdgRules>
  <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="L" MDBkTyp="2" MktDepth="5" MktDepthTmIntvl="3500" MDRcvryTmIntvl="30000" SvcLctnID1="224.0.50.82" SvcLctnSubID1="59500" SvcLctnID2="224.0.50.210" SvcLctnSubID2="59500"/>
  <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="HS" MDBkTyp="2" MktDepth="10" MDRcvryTmIntvl="120000" SvcLctnID1="224.0.50.106" SvcLctnSubID1="59500" SvcLctnID2="224.0.50.234" SvcLctnSubID2="59500"/>
  <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="HI" MDBkTyp="2" MktDepth="10" MktDepthTmIntvl="0" SvcLctnID1="224.0.50.107" SvcLctnSubID1="59501" SvcLctnID2="224.0.50.235" SvcLctnSubID2="59501"/>
</MktDef>
<SecDef PriSetPx="1.11">
  <Instrmt ID="478944" Src="M" SecTyp="FUT" Status="1" ProdCmplx="1" CFI="FFMCSX" MatDt="2017-05-23" MMY="201705" Mult="168" ValMeth="FUT" SettlMeth="C" PxPrcsn="3" MinPxIncr="0.001" MinPxIncrAmt="0.001">
    <AID AltID="41418776" AltIDSrc="M"/>
    <AID AltID="XF000003VLD7" AltIDSrc="4"/>
    <Evnt EventTyp="7" Dt="2017-05-23"/>
  </Instrmt>
  <MktSegGrp MktSegID="19481">
    <SecTrdgRules>
      <BaseTrdgRules>
        <PxRngRules PxRngRuleID="178"/>
      </BaseTrdgRules>
    </SecTrdgRules>
  </MktSegGrp>
</SecDef>
<SecDef PriSetPx="0.001">
  <Instrmt ID="488484" Src="M" SecTyp="FUT" Status="1" ProdCmplx="1" CFI="FFMCSX" MatDt="2017-06-28" MMY="201706" Mult="168" ValMeth="FUT" SettlMeth="C" PxPrcsn="3" MinPxIncr="0.001" MinPxIncrAmt="0.001">
    <AID AltID="41418777" AltIDSrc="M"/>
    <AID AltID="XF0000044BK7" AltIDSrc="4"/>
    <Evnt EventTyp="7" Dt="2017-06-28"/>
  </Instrmt>
  <MktSegGrp MktSegID="19481">
    <SecTrdgRules>
      <BaseTrdgRules>
        <PxRngRules PxRngRuleID="178"/>
      </BaseTrdgRules>
    </SecTrdgRules>
  </MktSegGrp>
</SecDef>
<MktDef MktID="XEEE" MktSegID="19482" EfctvBizDt="2017-05-22" NxtEfctvBizDt="2017-05-23" MktSeg="C1B5" MarketSegmentDesc="GERMAN INTRADAY CAP FUTURE" Sym="DE000A160P13" ParentMktSegmID="FENE" Ccy="EUR" MktSegStat="1" USFirmFlag="Y" PartID="10">
  <MtchRules MtchRuleProdCmplx="1" MtchAlgo="PT"/>
  <BaseTrdgRules QtSideInd="1" FastMktPctg="0">
    <TickRules TickRuleProdCmplx="1" StartTickPxRng="0" EndTickPxRng="99999.9999" TickIncr="0.001"/>
    <QuotSizeRules MinBidSz="1" MinOfrSz="1" FastMktInd="0"/>
    <QuotSizeRules MinBidSz="1" MinOfrSz="1" FastMktInd="1"/>
    <PxRngRules PxRngRuleID="178" PxRngProdCmplx="1" StartPxRng="0" EndPxRng="99999.9999" PxRngValu="0.5"/>
  </BaseTrdgRules>
  <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="L" MDBkTyp="2" MktDepth="5" MktDepthTmIntvl="3500" MDRcvryTmIntvl="30000" SvcLctnID1="224.0.50.82" SvcLctnSubID1="59500" SvcLctnID2="224.0.50.210" SvcLctnSubID2="59500"/>
  <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="HS" MDBkTyp="2" MktDepth="10" MDRcvryTmIntvl="120000" SvcLctnID1="224.0.50.106" SvcLctnSubID1="59500" SvcLctnID2="224.0.50.234" SvcLctnSubID2="59500"/>
  <MDFeedTyps MDFeedTyp="HI" MDBkTyp="2" MktDepth="10" MktDepthTmIntvl="0" SvcLctnID1="224.0.50.107" SvcLctnSubID1="59501" SvcLctnID2="224.0.50.235" SvcLctnSubID2="59501"/>
</MktDef>
<SecDef PriSetPx="0.001">
  <Instrmt ID="483881" Src="M" SecTyp="FUT" Status="1" ProdCmplx="1" CFI="FFMCSX" MatDt="2017-06-29" MMY="201706" Mult="168" ValMeth="FUT" SettlMeth="C" PxPrcsn="3" MinPxIncr="0.001" MinPxIncrAmt="0.001">
    <AID AltID="41484313" AltIDSrc="M"/>
    <AID AltID="XF00000407E7" AltIDSrc="4"/>
    <Evnt EventTyp="7" Dt="2017-06-29"/>
  </Instrmt>
  <MktSegGrp MktSegID="19482">
    <SecTrdgRules>
      <BaseTrdgRules>
        <PxRngRules PxRngRuleID="178"/>
      </BaseTrdgRules>
    </SecTrdgRules>
  </MktSegGrp>
</SecDef>
<SecDef PriSetPx="0.001">
  <Instrmt ID="491783" Src="M" SecTyp="FUT" Status="1" ProdCmplx="1" CFI="FFMCSX" MatDt="2017-07-06" MMY="201707" Mult="168" ValMeth="FUT" SettlMeth="C" PxPrcsn="3" MinPxIncr="0.001" MinPxIncrAmt="0.001">
    <AID AltID="41484314" AltIDSrc="M"/>
    <AID AltID="XF0000047E32" AltIDSrc="4"/>
    <Evnt EventTyp="7" Dt="2017-07-06"/>
  </Instrmt>
  <MktSegGrp MktSegID="19482">
    <SecTrdgRules>
      <BaseTrdgRules>
        <PxRngRules PxRngRuleID="178"/>
      </BaseTrdgRules>
    </SecTrdgRules>
  </MktSegGrp>
</SecDef>
  </Batch>
</FIXML>
```

And this is my XSLT code,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                          xmlns:x="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2" 
                          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2 fixml-main-5-0-SP2_.xsd"
                          xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
                          exclude-result-prefixes="xs math">

  <xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

  <xsl:param name="delim" select="','" />
  <xsl:param name="quote" select="'&quot;'" />
  <xsl:param name="break" select="'&#xA;'" />

  <xsl:template match="x:PxRngRules">

<xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(@PxRngRuleID), $quote)" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
<xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(@PxRngProdCmplx), $quote)" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
<xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(@StartPxRng), $quote)" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
<xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(@EndPxRng), $quote)" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
<xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(@PxRngValu), $quote)" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
```

Problem 1: I am trying to add below code to get the attribute names as column names

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:text>PxRngRuleID,PxRngProdCmplx,StartPxRng,EndPxRng,PxRngValu</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
```

But what I am getting is all the column names but not the values.

This is the sample output what I am getting after adding the above code before xsl:template.

```
   PxRngRuleID  PxRngProdCmplx  StartPxRng  EndPxRng    PxRngValu
   PxRngRuleID  PxRngProdCmplx  StartPxRng  EndPxRng    PxRngValu
   PxRngRuleID  PxRngProdCmplx  StartPxRng  EndPxRng    PxRngValu
```

Problem 2: If I want to add some more columns of the parent tag attributes, then what are all the changes I have to do ?
for example if I want to add the another column with "QtSideInd" in  parent tag and "MktSegID" in  tag.

I have tried with below, but not able to get the values,

```
 <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(../@QtSideInd), $quote)" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
 <xsl:value-of select="concat($quote, normalize-space(../../@MktSegID), $quote)" /><xsl:value-of select="$delim" />
```

This is my java code...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.text.ParseException;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stax.StAXSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

  public class ChunkXSLT {

public static int transform(InputStream is, OutputStream os, Transformer transformer, QName name) throws XMLStreamException, TransformerException {
    long time1 = System.nanoTime();
    // Open input & output files
    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, true);
    factory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_VALIDATING, false);
    XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(is);
    // In case you want to check which implementation is used.
    // Woodstox is a bit faster, but not worth adding extra dependency.


    Result result = new StreamResult(os);

    int count = 0;
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        if (reader.getEventType() == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT && name.equals(reader.getName())) {
            // System.out.println("FOUND " + count);
            count++;
            transformer.transform(new StAXSource(reader), result);
            if (count % 1000 == 0) {
                long time2 = System.nanoTime();
                double ms = (time2 - time1) / 1000000.0;
                System.out.format("Time=%.2fms Rows=%d%n", ms, count);
            }
        } else if (reader.getEventType() == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT) {
//                    System.out.println("Start "+reader.getName()+" != "+name);
        }
        reader.next();
    }
    long time2 = System.nanoTime();
    double ms = (time2 - time1) / 1000000.0;
    System.out.format("Total Time=%.2fms Total rows=%d%n", ms, count);
    return count;
}

public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {
    // Parse command line options
    File xsltFile;
    File inputFile;
    File outputFile;
    String tagName;
    String namespace;
    try {
        String xsltFileName = parse("-x", arg, "XSLT sheet", true);
        String inputFileName = parse("-f", arg, "Input file", true);
        String outputFileName = parse("-o", arg, "Output file", true);
        tagName = parse("-t", arg, "Tag name", true);
        namespace = parse("-n", arg, "Tag Namespace URL", false);
        xsltFile = new File(xsltFileName);
        inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
        outputFile = new File(outputFileName);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.err.println("Syntax: ChunkXSLT -f <input file> -o <output file> -x <XSLT stylesheet> -t <Tag name> [-n <namespace URL>]");
        System.err.println("Will split given file on given tag with given namespace.");
        System.err.println("Will process contents of each tag using given XSLT.");
        System.exit(1);
        return;
    }
    if (!xsltFile.exists()) {
        System.err.println("File not found " + xsltFile.getAbsolutePath());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    if (!inputFile.exists()) {
        System.err.println("File not found " + inputFile.getAbsolutePath());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // Open XSLT stylesheet
    StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(xsltFile);
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(stylesource);

    // Create XML tag name which is used to break up XML into rows
    final QName name;
    if (namespace != null) {
        name = new QName(namespace, tagName);
    } else {
        name = new QName(tagName);
    }
    System.out.println("Will look for tag " + name + " in namespace " + namespace);

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        // Open input & output files
        fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        transform(fis, fos, transformer, name);
    } finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            fos.close();
        }
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
    }
}

// Teo - inefficient, but who cares
private static String parse(String option, String[] arg, String desc, boolean required) throws ParseException {
    for (int i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) {
        if (option.equals(arg[i])) {
            if (i + 1 < arg.length) {
                String value = arg[i + 1].trim();
                return value;
            } else {
                throw new ParseException(option + " must be followed by an argument", i);
            }
        }
    }
    if (required) {
        throw new ParseException(desc + " is required", 0);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:text>PxRngRuleID,PxRngProdCmplx,StartPxRng,EndPxRng,PxRngValu</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
```

to

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:text>PxRngRuleID,PxRngProdCmplx,StartPxRng,EndPxRng,PxRngValu</xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::x:PxRngRules"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

to make sure your those elements are processed by the template you have written.

Comment: With this I am able to get the values but there is one problem, The column names are also repeating every time.

Comment: I have solely looked at the XSLT and corrected that. It seems yo java code is trying to call the same stylesheet repeatedly, so of course that way you would get the output repeated. It is not clear why you are doing that and what you want to achieve that way.

Comment: Hi Martin, Actually this is was not completely written by me. If possible could you please suggest me a good approach in the code w.r.t xslt which will have good performance and better execution time w.r.t current code. Thanks in Advance!